# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'title' of object '#<Object>' - React JS and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I click on Add button, all input values are save in reducer.
But if I add any character with previous value in input fields then I am getting mentioned error

**Cannot assign to read only property 'title' of object '#'**

**TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'title' of object '#'**

React js component code is:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import InputGroup from "react-bootstrap/InputGroup";
import { Product, addProduct } from "../Slice/ProductsSlice";
import { useAppDisptach } from "../store";

const ProductForm: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDisptach();

  const [product, setProduct] = useState<Product>({
    id: "",
    title: "",
    price: 0,
  });

  const { id, title, price } = product;

  const handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setProduct((prev) => {
    console.log('handleChange - ', prev);
    (prev as any)[name] = value;
    const newValue = { ...prev };
    return newValue;
  });

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addProduct(product));

  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Add Game to the Store</h2>
      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
        <Form.Control
          placeholder="Games Title"
          aria-label="Games Title"
          name={`title`}
          value={title}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <Form.Control
          placeholder="Price"
          aria-label="Price"
          name={`price`}
          type="number"
          value={price}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <Form.Control
          placeholder="Id"
          aria-label="Id"
          name={`id`}
          value={id}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </InputGroup>
      <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Product</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is attempting to mutate the state object, which is disallowed:

```
(prev as any)[name] = value;
```

But then immediately afterward the code creates a new object anyway:

```
const newValue = { ...prev };
```

So instead of mutating and then creating a new object, just create a new object and include the new value on it:

```
console.log('handleChange - ', prev);
const newValue = { ...prev, [name]: value };
return newValue;
```